# How to fix apple push notifications recieved through firebase for react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-firebase

I've configured for notification in iOS. 
Generated certificate request locally and added apn to developer account.
Added the certificate to keychain access.

Configured and connected my firebase account in iOS using the package manager.
Added the Google-info.plist.

Did i miss any step in configuration. Also i followed the steps in react-native-firebase documentation for configuring for Cloud Messaging.

I've already followed the steps to configured the apn and firebase. including a step which has been missed by the rn-firebase documentation.

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage(message => {
      // Process your message as required
      Alert.alert('Notification',JSON.stringify(message))
      console.info("Messaging ", message);
    });
    firebase.messaging().hasPermission().then(enabled => {
      enabled ?
        firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic("testopic") :
        firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(enabledNow => {
          enabledNow ?
            firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic("testopic") : '';
        }).catch(err => {
          Alert.alert('Notification', 'Enable notification to recieve attractive updates!')
        });
    })
    // Background Notification handler
    firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
      .then((notificationOpen) => {
        if (notificationOpen) {
          // App was opened by a notification
          // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
          const action = notificationOpen.action;
          // Get information about the notification that was opened
          const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        }
      });

    this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification) => {
      // Process your notification as required
      // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.

    });
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
      // Process your notification as required
      Alert.alert('Notification',JSON.stringify(notification))

    });
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
      const action = notificationOpen.action;
      // Get information about the notification that was opened
      const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationDisplayedListener();
    this.notificationListener();
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
  }
```

Appdelegate.m File

```c
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  #ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
  #endif

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"customerapp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  // Setup Notifications
  if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
    // iOS 10 or later
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
    UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
     requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
     completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
       if (error) { NSLog(@"%@", error); }
     }];
  } else {
    // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  }
  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];


  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self]; 
  // return YES;
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}


// URL Scheme responder
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{


  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}


@end
```

Comment: did you add all methods in AppDelegate.m ?

Comment: please share appdelegate.m

Comment: Please follow this instructions : []https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/ios

Comment: sorry have added *appdelegate.m* file. @Iva

Comment: Have shared @Codesingh

Comment: Add [RNFirebaseNotifications configure]; right after [FIRApp configure];

Comment: @Codesingh thanks for the hint. It's popping some error like
`{"framesToPop":1,"code":"messaging/permission_error"}`

Comment: please go through https://github.com/blankg/react-native-firebase/commit/cb82530e04942c2a6fecf6a75f254453534d3b56

Comment: @Codesingh updated code to

```firebase.messaging().hasPermission().then(enabled => { enabled ? firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic("testopic") : firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(enabledNow => { enabledNow ? firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic("testopic") : ''; }).catch(err => { Alert.alert('Notification', 'Enable notification to recieve attractive updates!') }); })`
```
still an issue

Comment: Please share the console so that i can see if there is problem in javascript code.

Comment: My Bad. Did'nt configure the apn in firebase. Thanks for your help!